# Loading from Google cloud storage to Big Query seems slow

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm running a test using Big Query. Basically I have 50,000 files, each of which are 27MB in size, on average. Some larger, some smaller.

Timing each file upload reveals:

real    0m49.868s
user    0m0.297s
sys 0m0.173s

Using something similar to:

time bq load --encoding="UTF-8" --field_delimiter="~" dataset gs://project/b_20130630_0003_1/20130630_0003_4565900000.tsv schema.json

Running command: "bq ls -j"  and subsequently running "bq show -j " reveals that I have the following errors:

Job Type    State      Start Time      Duration   Bytes Processed

---

load       FAILURE   01 Jul 22:21:18   0:00:00

Errors encountered during job execution. Exceeded quota: too many imports per table for this table

After checking the database, the rows seems to of loaded fine which is puzzling since, given the error, I would of expected nothing to of gotten loaded.  The problem is that I really don't understand how I reached my quota limit since I've only just started 
uploading files recently and thought the limit was 200,000 requests.

All the data is currently on Google Cloud Storage so I would expect the data loading to happen fairly quickly since the interaction is between cloud storage and Big Query both of which are in the cloud.

By my calculations the entire load is going to take: (50,000 * 49 seconds) 28 days.

Kinda hoping these numbers are wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: Went back and carefully read BQ command line utility help. It seems I was loading each file as a separate load job. I think this was causing the problem. It wasn't immediately obvious to me (duh!) that you could use globbing instead of load each file, i.e., bq load --encoding="UTF-8" --field_delimiter="~" dataset gs://cs/b_20130630_0003_1/* schema.json.  Note the wild card. Will try to perform a load job with 10,000 files which is the maximum.

Comment: im very interested to know what exactly this was for! thats an insane amount of files

Answer (score 3):

The quota limit per table is 1000 loads per day. This is to encourage people to batch their loads, since we can generate a more efficient representation of the table if we can see more of the data at once.

BigQuery can perform load jobs in parallel. Depending on the size of your load, a number of workers will be assigned to your job. If your files are large, those files will be split among workers; alternately if you pass multiple files, each worker may process a different file. So the time that it takes for one file is not indicative of the time that it takes to run a load job with multiple files.

Comment: I eventually figured this out. I had previously setup a bunch of Google compute computers for something else that I was working on and did the parallel loads as you so rightfully pointed out. This aspect of loading was something I previously missed. Anyway, at the end of the day I had uploaded 10 billion rows. Cheers.

Comment: @jordan Do these 1000 loads also runs parallel?

Comment: @jordan
A different question: Will it follow any ordering on execution if have ongoing Stream + DML statements + Bulk loads for same table?